# Docker: Issue creating a Portainer container

Tags: docker, docker-run, portainer

I'm trying to create a Portainer container in Windows 10 (and Docker ToolBox), but I'm getting an error using this `docker run` command:

```
docker run --name portainer --restart unless-stopped -p 9090:9000 -e TZ=America/Chicago -it --mount src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock,type=volume --mount src="/c/Users/My Cloud/AppData/Roaming/DockerConfigs/Portainer/Data",dst=/data,type=bind portainer/portainer
```

Is giving me this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create /var/run/docker.sock: "/var/run/docker.sock" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
```

If I follow the Windows example on the [Portainer page](https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html) replace the `--mount` version of the `docker.sock` path with the `-v` version instead, like this:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I get this error instead:

```
2019/02/13 19:47:49 invalid argument
```

But the container *does* get created; however, it ignored the specified ports in the command-line, and when I try to manually re-add them using Kitematic, it starts a bootloop on that container, and the container is unusable, I end up having to scrap it.

Anyone know what I'm missing? I'm just now learning my way around Docker.

Comment: Can you open an issue at https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues ? We'll need more details about your environment in order to be able to help you. This article could also be handy: https://lemariva.com/blog/2018/05/tutorial-portainer-for-local-docker-environments-on-windows-10

Comment: ... leave it to me to always run into issues no one is able to answer .... LOL